# change of units from radius to volume

Tags: calculus

I have force as a function of radius:

$\frac{1}{r^3}- \frac{1}{r^2}$

I integrate that to get energy as a function of radius. (Energy = Force * distance) So far so good. Now the radius actually corresponds to a volume

$V=\frac{4 \pi}{3} r^3$

I would very much like to know how much pressure it takes to cause a given change of volume. 
Pressure has units of energy per volume so I assume that what I need is

$\frac{dE/dr}{dV/dr}$

I tried several things but wolfram says I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the setup of the question you are asking entirely, but pressure also has units of [force]/[area] which might be useful here.

Comment: The fractional exponents were throwing me off. I see now that they cancel out